# SQL Math prob involving averaging values (but not how you think!)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm very new to SQL and having trouble getting a SQL query to work.

I have a list of responses that contain the numbers 1 through 4 Example:

Question 1 contains the data Q1: 1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,4,2

What I need to do is count how many 1's and 2's there are, total them and then average the number. Such as in the above example have a count that there are 6 1's and 2's total and divide that by the total number for a average.  6/10 = .6 (oh gosh I hope that made sense)

I have been trying this code but it is summing the numbers and then dividing by the total.

```
Select avg(q1) as avg
From db
Where q1 between 1 and 2
And call = 55817
```

Such as in the above example it's doing this: `1+2+1+1+2+2=9/10 = .9` when again I need it to just "count" how many 1's and 2's there are.

Comment: This isn't an average by any definition, it's a ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an SQLite specific solution, try this:

```
SELECT AVG(q1 IN (1, 2)) AS youravg
FROM db
WHERE call = 55817
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6d08d/3)

For a more standard SQL solution, you might prefer this:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN q1 IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS youravg
FROM db
WHERE call = 55817
```

Comment: I think the OP really wants `COUNT(CASE WHEN q1 IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(1)`

Comment: Duh (me), of course. I see now. I was so hung up on the abuse of the term "average" I didn't see through what you were doing. Nice one!

Comment: Mark, you are my savior, I can't explain how many websites I've been through and you solved it in a matter of minutes, kudos to you!

Comment: @user1553094 - don't forget to give Mark the tick `:)`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a SELECT with 1 and 2 then use the COUNT function?

[COUNT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php)